# Function template partial specialization - are there any workaround?

Tags: c++, templates

I have the following function

```
enum class NodeCachingOptions
{
    AddPath,
    DontAddPath
};

template <typename T, NodeCachingOptions>
T* CreateSObject(const MPath& path)
```

Idea was to specialize function for different NodeCachingOptions.

Turned out it is impossible to use partial function template specialization, thus I tried a workaround:

```
template <typename T, NodeCachingOptions>
T* CreateSObject(const MPath& ob)
{
   CreateSObject_Impl<class T, NodeCachingOptions> temp
   return temp.call(ob);
}

template <typename T, NodeCachingOptions>
struct CreateSObject_Impl
{
    T* call(const MPath& ob);
};

template <typename T>
struct CreateSObject_Impl<typename T, NodeCachingOptions::AddPath>
{
   T* call(const MDagPath& ob)
   {…}
}
template <typename T>
struct CreateSObject_Impl<typename T, NodeCachingOptions::DontAddPath>
{…}
```

However I'm getting compile error: ::NodeCachingOptions': illegal type for non-type template parameter '__formal'

What am I doing wrong and is there a better way to solve this problem?

I took idea of struct impl from here: [Partial template specialization of free functions - best practices](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2403928/partial-template-specialization-of-free-functions-best-practices)

Comment: There is something very strange in your code. When you say "Idea was to specialize function for different NodeCachingOptions", what do you mean? You mean for different implementations of NodeCachingOptions or if NodeCachingOptions value is AddPath or DontAddPath?

Comment: Your first template function has a syntax issue anyway. You can't just give an existing class name in a template declaration like that.

Comment: CreateSObject should have different implementation for NodeCachingOptions::AddPath and NodeCachingOptions::DontAddPath. I don't want to write 2 different functions (e.g. CreateSObject_DontSavePath(…) and CreateSObject(...)   )

Comment: How is that different from e.g. template <class T, int N>
struct mul_impl <>  ...       template <class T>
struct mul_impl<T, 0> ?    (I looke here for example: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2403928/partial-template-specialization-of-free-functions-best-practices)

Comment: Ok I understand what you want to do now (thanks to the answer below). I was thinking something totally different, my bad.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your syntax is all wrong. Make it

```
template <typename T, NodeCachingOptions opt>
T* CreateSObject(const MPath& ob)
{
   CreateSObject_Impl<T, opt> temp;
   return temp.call(ob);
}
```

You pass the *value* of type `NodeCachingOptions` as the second template paramter of `CreateSObject_Impl`, not the type itself.

You may want to make `call` a static member of `CreateSObject_Impl`, and write `return CreateSObject_Impl<T, opt>::call(ob);`

Comment: and be careful with that, the `NodeCachingOptions` object you will pass as a template to your methods must be const. Else you have to find another way.

Comment: oh, I see. Thanks!